# SSO authorization in Directus using the keycloak provider

Tags: keycloak, directus

Good afternoon, how can I set up sso authorization from keycloak in my directus application? Below I will give the settings for my directus image. And the error that occurs when trying to log into the account.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into this the other day and redirect_uri is picked up from the PUBLIC_URL environment variable, which should be set as well. So you may wish to ensure this is set. You may also want to consider making your root url and base url simply `http://localhost:8055` and making `/*` your valid redirect url, and narrow it down from there.